# How can I grab a ticket via the salesforce1 mobile app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, salesforce1-platform

Is there a way to take ownership of a case in a queue via the SalesForce1 mobile app? I can adjust other fields in a case but I can't seem to change the owner field and don't see a default button to grab a case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Salesforce1 doesn't support changing Ownership fields natively.

Reference :
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187705&language=en_US

Pending Idea :
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kyOeAAI

couple of options I can think of

1. try using [custom publisher action](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000182001&language=en_US) to change the record owner..
2. follow the steps in this @bob's [blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com.au/2014/07/taking-record-ownership-in-salesforce1.html)